# SubmitForm weird behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had implemented a preview button and a save button in a profile page, submitting a form to two different pages. One with the code to save data, and one where is a fake page that show the informations as the original page will show.
This is the code

```
<form id="personal-information-form" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!--Some code to recollect info -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(action)
{
    document.getElementById('personal-information-form').action = action;
document.getElementById('personal-information-form').setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    document.getElementById('personal-information-form').submit();
}
</script>       
  <p><input type="submit" name="preview-info" class="my-buttons"  onclick="submitForm('url_to_preview')" value="Preview" >&nbsp;
    <span><input type="submit" name="save-info" class="my-buttons" value="Save"></span></p>
     </form>
```

If I click once on one of the two buttons, all work fine.
If I click in the preview first and then in the save button, the save button don't save the info, instead show me the preview page. Why? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the Preview button you are permanently setting the `action` attribute of the `form` to the preview URL.

Generally I would prefer to do something like this with AJAX rather than with form hackery, but you could amend your current solution like this:

```
function submitForm(action, target) {
    var form = document.getElementById('personal-information-form');    
    var originalTarget = form.target;
    var originalAction = form.action;
    form.setAttribute("target", target || "_self");
    form.action = action;
    form.submit();
    form.target = originalTarget;
    form.action = originalAction;
    return false;
}
```

This will restore the current action and target after submitting. (Haven't tested; let me know how this goes).

Then your `onclick` for the Preview button should say `submitForm('url_to_preview', '_blank')`.

Comment: Edited with one possible solution.

Comment: When you click preview, the preview page is open, but the original page is refreshed. How can I fix it?

Comment: Hmm you might need a `return false;` to disable the default form submit. Try now?

Comment: I deleted the last two line `form.target = originalTarget;
    form.action = originalAction;` and putted a `submitform('')` in the other link. Now work. Thanx :)